# How to get Facebook Persistent Stream Key?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to obtain Persistent Stream Key trough graph api? I do see option 'Use a persistent stream key' on the configure [stream page](https://www.facebook.com/live/create). But there is no parameter to set it by [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video#Creating). I'd like publish the stream when it's stopped but keep the same key for streaming. Looks like I have to create a new key every time but it's quite inconvenient.